# Is this an error in gcc's overload resolution?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm writing a resource management class, called `Wraiiper`. End goal is to be able to write things like

```
Wraiiper wr(new ClassA(), destroyA); // cleanup with destroyA 
wr.push_back(new ClassB());          // cleanup with delete
```

so it's basically of dynamic size, accepts any type, and deletes with either `delete` or a custom deallocator. I guess it does the same job that a `std::vector<boost:any>` would do if I inserted unique pointers to the various elements. The code (**[coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/848eba39dd48181b)**) follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>


namespace dpol
{ // destruction policies
    template<typename Func>
    struct Destruction
    {
        Func finalize; 

        Destruction(Func f) : finalize(f)
        {
        }
        template<typename T>
        void apply(T* data)
        {
            if (data) finalize(data); 
        }
    };
    template<>
    struct Destruction<void>
    {
        template<typename T>
        void apply(T* data)
        {
            delete data; 
        }
    };
} // destruction policies

class Wraiiper
{
    struct ResourceConcept
    {
        virtual ~ResourceConcept() {}
        virtual void* get() = 0; 
    };    

    template<typename T, typename Func>
    struct ResourceModel : ResourceConcept, dpol::Destruction<Func>
    {
        T* data; 

        ResourceModel(T* data)
            : dpol::Destruction<Func>()
            , data(data)
        { // a. One arg constructor
        }
        ResourceModel(T* data, Func f)
            : dpol::Destruction<Func>(f)
            , data(data)
        { // b. Two args constructor
        }
        ~ResourceModel()
        {
            dpol::Destruction<Func>::apply(data); 
        }

        void* get()
        {
            return data; 
        }
    };

    std::vector<ResourceConcept*> resource; 

public:

  template<typename T, typename Func>
  Wraiiper(T* data, Func f)
  {
      resource.push_back(new ResourceModel<T, Func>(data, f)); 
  }
  template<typename T>
  Wraiiper(T* data)
  {
      resource.push_back(new ResourceModel<T, void>(data)); 
  }
  ~Wraiiper()
  {
      while (!resource.empty())
      {
          delete resource.back(); 
          resource.pop_back(); 
      }
  }

  template<typename T, typename Func>
  T* push_back(T* data, Func f)
  {
      resource.push_back(new ResourceModel<T, Func>(data, f)); 
      return get<T*>(resource.size()-1); 
  }
  template<typename T>
  T* push_back(T* data)
  {
      resource.push_back(new ResourceModel<T, void>(data)); 
      return get<T*>(resource.size()-1); 
  }

  template<typename T>
  T  get(std::size_t i = 0)
  {
      return (T)resource.at(0)->get(); 
  }
};

struct A
{
    int val; 
    A(int x) : val(x) {}
};

void dela(A *arg) { delete arg; }

int main()
{
    Wraiiper wr(new A(2), dela); // compiles fine
    Wraiiper wr2(new double);    // error !

    return 0;
}
```

### Question

The following error bothers me

> main.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct Wraiiper::ResourceModel':
>
> main.cpp:79:7:   required from 'Wraiiper::Wraiiper(T*) [with T = double]'
>
> main.cpp:121:28:   required from here
>
> main.cpp:51:9: error: invalid parameter type 'void'
>
> ```
>     ResourceModel(T* data, Func f)
>
>     ^
> ```
>
> main.cpp:51:9: error: in declaration 'Wraiiper::ResourceModel::ResourceModel(T*, Func)'

My argument is that the constructor (a) with one argument `ResourceModel(T* data)` should be selected when instantiating `Wraiiper::ResourceModel<double, void>` since **I explicitly call it with one argument**

What is happening here, why is there an error and how could I overcome it ?

FWIW this also fails (the same error) in Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Compile with [clang++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fa5dbb736b2dfbe) which will give you a better error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My argument is that the constructor (a) with one argument ResourceModel(T* data) should be selected when instantiating Wraiiper::ResourceModel since I explicitly call it with one argument

Calling the function is not the problem; instantiating `ResourceModel<double, void>` is. You may not be calling that problematic function but it still has to be semantically valid at the point of instantiation:

> `[C++11: 14.7.1/1]:` *[..]* **The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit instantiation of the declarations**, but not of the definitions or default arguments, **of the class member functions**, member classes, scoped member enumerations, static data members and member templates; *[..]*

… and as long as it tries to take a `double*` and a `void`, that criterion is not met.

[Clang's diagnostic output makes this marginally clearer](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fa5dbb736b2dfbe):

> ```
> clang++ -std=c++11 -O2 -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
> main.cpp:51:37: error: argument may not have 'void' type
>         ResourceModel(T* data, Func f)
>                                     ^
> main.cpp:79:30: note: in instantiation of template class 'Wraiiper::ResourceModel<double, void>' requested here
>       resource.push_back(new ResourceModel<T, void>(data)); 
>                              ^
> main.cpp:121:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Wraiiper::Wraiiper<double>' requested here
>     Wraiiper wr2(new double);    // error !
>              ^
> 1 error generated.
> ```

You *may* able to disable it for this specialisation with `std::enable_if`. Otherwise I guess you'll need to specialise `ResourceModel` for the `<..., void>` case. An alternative is to send a singular function into `ResourceModel` rather than none at all, though you'd still need to pick a passable type for it.

Comment: Yes, makes sense. Maybe I'll try making both constructors templated then to have SFINAE apply implicitly

Comment: Perhaps provide a quote from the standard that says that declarations of member functions are instantiated if the class is.

Comment: OK, if both constructors are templatized only the one used is instantiated every time, so compilation [succeeds](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/822461cd4f0589dd), thnx man